# How to Implement Drag and Drop using React With Redux , ES6?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-dnd

I have to implement Drag And Drop using the 
`

> **react-dnd** https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dnd

We knew that Redux makes things easier , But when we integrating **React , Redux , to make use of Drag And Drop** its get complicated , I am facing the following issues when i do this.

- Examples are mostly from ES7 ,
- When Connecting to Redux no idea **"how to dispatch actions"** (in a Proper Way),
- Too hard to understand the flow **as a Beginner**

**Is There any Right way to Do it ? or Any Simple Examples**

Comment: There's example using ES6/ES5, you just have to click on the toggle buttons.http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs-faq.html#what-is-the-syntax-i-see-in-the-es7-code-examples-

Answer (score 0):

After Some research i got to know that ,

1.react-dnd is inbuild with **redux** there are no difficulties in Dispatch actions ,

2.We have to convert ES7 to ES6 in the following way

> ES7

```
import { DragSource } from 'react-dnd';

@DragSource(type, spec, collect)
export default class MyComponent {
  /* ... */
}
```

> We have make use of ES6 in the below way

```
import { DragSource } from 'react-dnd';

class MyComponent {
  /* ... */
}

export default DragSource(type, spec, collect)(MyComponent);
```

> You can get the examples from the below link

```
https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs-faq.html
```